# jQuery is not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

jQuery is not working in Firefox. It works fine in IE and Google chrome, but when I am trying to run my application in Mozilla Firefox jQuery is not working. Any guesses?
*Here is my piece of code*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <style>
         div{
         width:200px;
         height:100px;
         border:1px solid red;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div> One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
      <div>Three</div>
   </body>
   <script>
      $('div').click(function(){
       alert("Hello.....");
      });
   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yVk53/ - works fine for me

Comment: @Chris Go and view the source of that jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/yVk53/show/) and you'll see it actually wraps all of your code inside another `body` element, so it's not a fair test.

Comment: Yeah..Its working for me from jsfiddle. But,if I open same application(same code that is saved in my deskop) in my brower,its not working....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should use the dom ready event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').click(function(){
   alert("Hello.....");
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah...You are right...I would make your answer as accepted one..But I have a doubt..I had written my script at end of the body, so it must be equivalent to document.ready() na!!!

Comment: @RamaRaoM did you read the other answers? It's probably because your script isn't in the body, but outside...

Comment: @RamaRaoM: A script outside the `<body>` and `<head>` tags is automatically moved into `<head>`. If you don't like the auto-correction then you should write valid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Put your jquery  Code inside `document.ready`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function(){
       alert("Hello.....");
      });

 });
```

Give your div a proper class.just like

```
<div class="clsDiv"> One</div>
```

amd call like this.

```
 $('.clsDiv').click(function(){
```

Comment: Why should he give a class to his div?

Answer (score 0):

lukenz and Shree nailed it.
JQUery event handlers for html elements must first be registered in $(document).ready().